# Operating System: Memory management multilevel paging concept

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, page-tables

In paging, when page table size is very much greater then page size we go for multilevel page table right??
So my concern is that how innermost page table get into page size although it's size is much greater then page size. And How outermost page table refer to innermost page table which is way larger then page size??

Please explain.
(First post on stack) :-)

Answer (score 0):

When the size of the page table must be larger than one page, multilevel paging is one of the options that facilitates page level memory-management.

In multi-level paging, the topmost level of the page table contains pointers to the next level page table. The bottommost level contains the actual physical page number or physical address. Intermediate levels contain pointers to lower levels. There can be any number of intermediate levels depending on the architecture used.

> how innermost page table get into page size although it's size is much greater then page size.

The lowest level *does* fit in only one page. Its size is not "much greater then (sic) page size".

> How outermost page table refer to innermost page table which is way larger then page size??

The higher levels of the page table contain pointers to the next level of the multi-level page table.

I think you might have some fundamental misunderstandings of how multi-level page tables work. Take a look at the diagrams [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table#Multilevel_page_tables).